# PartialView not recognised Error due to generic base controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I have the following controller definition

```
    public class BaseController<T> where T : Controller, new()
    {
       public ActionResult ShowACommonForm(T item)
        {
            //item is cached here
            var model = new model()
            return Partialiew(model);
        }
```

I get the following error
The name 'Partialiew' does not exist in the current context

if I remove the generic element of the class definition the error goes away.
can anyone please tell me why I cant get rid of the error?

its an action method to display a common form across multiple controllers so I want it generic for serialisation and deserialisation to the cache.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `BaseController` should be inheriting from `Controller` class.

Comment: `PartialView` not `Partialiew`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PartialView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.partialview?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is a protected method on `Controller`. Your `BaseController` does not inherit from `Controller`, so it won't have access to the methods you are expecting.

Comment: so changing the class signature to the following got rid of the error

public class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : new()
{
}